how to iterate through a *.shp file and plot a fraction of the total available shapes in folium
m = folium.Map([53, -113], zoom_start=8, control_scale=True)
minimap = plugins.MiniMap()
m.add_child(minimap)

map_shape = gpd.read_file("some_huge_shape_file.shp")
import random

def random_html_color():
    r = random.randint(0,256)
    g = random.randint(0,256)
    b = random.randint(0,256)
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (r, g, b)

def style_fcn(x):
    return { 'fillColor': random_html_color() }

def highlight_fcn(x):
    return { 'fillColor': '#ff0000' }

folium.GeoJson(data=map_shape, overlay=True, popup_keep_highlighted=True, style_function=style_fcn, highlight_function=highlight_fcn, tooltip = folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['DESREP']), opacity=0.1,
               popup=folium.GeoJsonPopup(fields=['TYPE', 'NUMBER'])
               ).add_to(m)

I have been reading the WHOLE shape file, the html file I get at the end is over 600mb which is not displaying/loading even in high end machines. So I am wondering if a fraction of this huge shape file can be plotted instead of the whole so that the final html file is light enough to be displayed whithout memory issues.

sampled_shape = map_shape.sample(frac=0.1, random_state=42) to sample 10% of the data randomly is one way

Thanks for the relevant response. Is there a "non-random" of splitting the file? I want to split it into a few non-overlapping chunks so that I don't miss any pieces


Is there a "non-random" of splitting the file? I want to split it into a few non-overlapping chunks..

It depends on the type of split you want. In any case, you could make a factory function to do so :
def splitter(df, fracs= None, n=None, k=None):
    """    
    df: the (geo)dataframe to split
    fracs: percentages (must sum to 1.0 or 100)
    n: number of sub-dataframes
    k: size of each sub-dataframe
    """
    import numpy as np
    assert fracs or n or k
    if fracs is not None:
        norm = np.array(fracs) / np.sum(fracs)
        cs = (np.cumsum(np.pad(norm, (1, 0))) * len(df)) - .1
        indices = np.digitize(np.arange(len(df)), cs)
    elif n is not None:
        indices = np.arange(len(df)) // np.ceil(len(df) / n)
    elif k is not None:
        indices = np.arange(len(df)) // k
    return [g for _, g in df.groupby(indices)]

for gdf in map_shape.pipe(splitter, n=6):
    m = gdf.pipe(_explore)
    m.save("{:03}-TO-{:03}.html".format(*gdf.index[[0, -1]] + 1))

This produces those html files :
001-TO-003.html > 0.07MB
004-TO-006.html > 0.04MB
007-TO-009.html > 0.04MB
010-TO-012.html > 0.04MB
013-TO-015.html > 0.03MB
016-TO-018.html > 0.03MB


Used input :
import geopandas as gpd

map_shape = gpd.read_file(
    "https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/110m/cultural/110m_cultural.zip",
    layer="ne_110m_admin_0_countries", where="CONTINENT = 'North America'"
).assign(**dict.fromkeys(["DESREP", "TYPE", "NUMBER"]))

def _explore(gdf, **kwargs):
    m = gdf.explore(
        location=[53, -113],
        zoom_start=2,
        control_scale=True,
        tooltip=["DESREP"],
        popup=["TYPE", "NUMBER"],
        style_kwds=dict(style_function=style_fcn),
        popup_kwds=dict(popup_keep_highlighted=True),
        highlight_kwds=dict(**highlight_fcn()), # remove `x` in def
        overlay=True,
        opacity=.1,
        **kwargs
    )
    import folium.plugins as plugins
    plugins.MiniMap().add_to(m)
    return m


You can specify filters when reading the file with geopandas.read_file. You can e.g. specify box=slice(10, 20) to read only row 10 till 20. Or you can specify box=(10000, 10000, 20000, 20000) to only read the polygons that intersect the box specified.
